# Can ARM PC register point to address not on instruction boundary?

Tags: assembly, arm

Here is GDB output I've received on some very rare SEGV while running application on linux, Cortex-A8:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb6341668 in strcpy () at ../ports/sysdeps/arm/armv6/strcpy.S:48
(gdb) info registers
r0             0x161598 1447320
r1             0x153eec 1392364
r2             0x161598 1447320
r3             0x2e     46
r4             0x0      0
r5             0xbb8    3000
r6             0xd8     216
r7             0xbefff408       3204445192
r8             0x0      0
r9             0x0      0
r10            0xb6fff000       3070226432
r11            0xa      10
r12            0x14d1e4 1364452
sp             0xbefff408       0xbefff408
lr             0x80461  525409
pc             0xb6341668       0xb6341668 <strcpy+8>
cpsr           0xf0030  983088
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function strcpy:
   0xb6341660 <+0>:     mov     r12, r0
   0xb6341662 <+2>:     pld     [r0]
   0xb6341666 <+6>:     pld     [r1]
   0xb634166a <+10>:    and.w   r3, r1, #7
   0xb634166e <+14>:    rsb     r3, r3, #16
   0xb6341672 <+18>:    ldrb.w  r2, [r1], #1
```

Stack trace and values passed to strcpy (upper backtrace frame) seem correct, but PC value is 0xb6341668 which is not at the beginning of any instruction in gdb disassembly. Is it legal?

Comment: PLD is a fairly recent addition to the instruction set. Does the CPU support it? If it's an "Illegal instruction" crash, PC could be anything.

Comment: It seems to be supported by ARMv7-A/Cortex-A8: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344i/Cbbbdaed.html . I would also expect SIGILL in this case (as e.g. libcrypto.so does apparently to test CPU capabilities).

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted, the PC is free to point anywhere that's sufficiently aligned - that's on a 4-byte boundary in ARM state, or a 2-byte boundary in Thumb state.

This particular situation gets more fun when you look at the machine code, and consider the significance of Thumb's variable-length encodings:

```
   0:   4684            mov     ip, r0
   2:   f890 f000       pld     [r0]
   6:   f891 f000       pld     [r1]
   a:   f001 0307       and.w   r3, r1, #7
   e:   f1c3 0310       rsb     r3, r3, #16
  12:   f811 2b01       ldrb.w  r2, [r1], #1
```

But hey, we're already in bugsville, so who says we had to start from `<strcpy>`? Let's try disassembling the same thing, but knocking off the first two halfwords to start from `<strcpy+4>` and throw the 32-bit encodings out of sync:

```
   //   4684 f890       (skipped)
   0:   f000 f891       bl      0x126
   4:   f000 f001       bl      0x40000a
   8:   0307            lsls    r7, r0, #12
   a:   f1c3 0310       rsb     r3, r3, #16
   e:   f811 2b01       ldrb.w  r2, [r1], #1
```

So there you go, if you point your PC at 0xb6341668 it sees a perfectly valid `bl . + 0x400006`, so if 0xb674166e is indeed unmapped (or mapped no-execute) then it's only right you should get a SEGV from trying to execute it. Now, how you might have wound up doing that is another matter entirely...

Comment: It might also be something completely different altogether, like taking an asynchronous data abort whilst executing 0xb6341660, and the saved PC delivered by the signal handler not being fixed up to hide the +8 byte exception return offset, but I'd have to go and dig into kernel code to verify that, and it's late.

Answer (score 1):

The processor is in [Thumb mode](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/ch02s02s09.html), which uses 16-bit instructions; [decode the `cpsr`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344i/ch02s14s08.html) to see what mode it's in.

Comment: It is in Thumb mode, but does it mean PC can point to address not present in disassembly ("middle of" pld instruction)?

Comment: arm in general when you branch to an address using the right instructions, if the lsbit is a zero then switch to arm mode on the way if the lsbit is a 1 then switch to thumb mode.  read up on the bx instruction in arm docs, full sized cores not the cortex-ms ARMv4T and newer.

Comment: note that the lsbit is stripped off when it goes into the program counter otherwise the pc relative stuff would be wrong (you can check the pc to verify anyway).  also note if you do this with the wrong instructions it will break as one might expect.

Comment: Look at `r0` and `r12`... they are not the same, yet the instruction at `0xb6341660` sets them the same. So, the path to `0xb6341668` is not through the start of the `strcpy` function if the disassembly is to be believed.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is certainly the source of the problem, there is no check in the processor to verify that it is at a valid instruction boundary. And there is actually no way to verify it: the processor just fetches the instructions, decodes if it looks like a 32-bit or 16-bit one, and executes it.

In this case, there is a good chance that one (junk) instruction is actually underfined, causes an alignment or MMU fault, as it is actually running random instructions.